# Does Alchemy support batch requests for getAssetTransfers?

Tags: alchemy, batch

I am trying to make a [batch request](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/batch-requests) for [getAssetTransfers endpoint](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-getassettransfers).

However, when I try to do this, I get this error:

```
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: 1,
    error: {
      code: -32600,
      message: 'Unsupported methods [alchemy_getAssetTransfers] in batch call. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis'
    }
  }
```

Is it not possible to batch this request? I cannot find the list of supported requests over HTTP anywhere in their documentation. This is the code I have:

```
async function batchAlchemyTxnRequests(fromBlockNumber, address1, address2) {
    let fromBlockNumberInHex = "0x" + fromBlockNumber.toString(16);

    let req1 = {
        method: 'alchemy_getAssetTransfers',
        params: [
            {
                fromBlock: fromBlockNumberInHex,
                toBlock: 'latest',
                toAddress: address1,
                category: ['erc721', 'erc1155', 'specialnft'],
                withMetadata: true,
                excludeZeroValue: true,
            },

        ],
        id: 1,
        jsonrpc: '2.0'
    };
    let req2 = {
        method: 'alchemy_getAssetTransfers',
        params: [
            {
                fromBlock: fromBlockNumberInHex,
                toBlock: 'latest',
                fromAddress: address2,
                category: ['erc721', 'erc1155', 'specialnft'],
                withMetadata: true,
                excludeZeroValue: true,
            },
        ],
        id: 2,
        jsonrpc: '2.0'
    };

    let reqs = [req1, req2];
    let baseUrl = 'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/'+config.ALCHEMY_API_KEY;

    const res = await fetch(
        baseUrl, {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: JSON.stringify(reqs), 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    ).catch (err => console.log(err));
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

I am trying to get ethereum-mainnet transactions for a list of addresses through the API, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is Killiane from Alchemy, I am following my answers from your ticket in the Alchemy Discord server here!

Unfortunately we currently do not support batching for our enhanced APIs, `alchemy_` methods like `alchemy_getAssetTransfers` cannot be batched. Also `debug_` and `trace_` methods cannot be batched either.

There is some workaround that would allow you to get similar data to `_getAssetTransfers` since asset transfers data is derived from:

- `eth_getBlockByNumber`: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-getblockbynumber
- `eth_getLogs`: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-getlogs
- `debug_traceBlockByNumber`: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/debug-traceblockbynumber

Both `eth_blockByNumber` and `eth_getLogs` can be batched I believe (or, at least in the case of logs, you can do from/to block ranges). However, there’s no way to batch traces right now!
But it’s some more work to interpret the responses of these endpoints and convert into transfer events I would say.

As we are constantly upgrading our products, your feedback is super valuable to us and we will work on integrating your feature-request into our roadmap!